# How can you draw a bezier curve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bezier

What's the Matlab way to draw a Bezier curve ? Do you have to prgoram it yourself ?

I am not looking for a user made routine, but am asking if Matlab offers a standard way to draw them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking and searching through the documentation, my answer is No: you'd have to go with one of the 3rd party implementations.

Likeliest candidate would be the `interp` family functions, and they implement no Bezier interpolation.

Comment: Thx. As I said in the other answer: I am actually asking this because I saw my son programming a Bezier curve himself in Matlab, I know that every drawing program implements this so I seemed to me that a program as Matlab should have this too.

Answer (score 4):

With the Curve Fitting Toolbox, Matlab supports B-splines, which are a generalization of Bézier curves. A rational B-spline with no internal knots is a Bézier spline.

For example

```
p = spmak([0 0 0 1 1 1],[1 0;0 1]);
fnplt(p)
```

would plot a Bézier curve with control points at (0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, http://www.cnblogs.com/begtostudy/articles/1787709.html

Answer (score 2):

The following code based on this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Explicit_definition).

```
function B = bazier( t, P )
    %Bazier curve
    % Parameters
    % ----------
    % - t: double
    %   Time between 0 and 1
    % - C: 2-by-n double matrix
    %   Control points
    %
    % Returns
    % -------
    % - B: 2-by-1 vector
    %   Output point

    B = [0, 0]';

    n = size(P, 2);
    for i = 1:n
        B = B + b(t, i - 1, n - 1) * P(:, i);
    end
end

function value = b(t, i, n)
    value = nchoosek(n, i) * t^i * (1 - t)^(n - i);
end
```