# Fit a curve in MATLAB where points have specified normals

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, spline

I have two 2D points `p1, p2` in MATLAB, and each point has a normal `n1, n2`. I wish to find the (cubic) polynomial which joins the two points and agrees with the specified normals at each end. Is there something built-in to MATLAB to do this?

Of course, I could derive the equations for the polynomial manually, but MATLAB's [curve fitting toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/curvefitting/)  has so much built-in that I assumed it would be possible. I haven't been able to find any examples of curve, spline or polynomial fitting where the normals are specified.

As an extrapolation of this, I would like to fit splines where each data point has a normal specified.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** If your points are points of a function, then you need [cubic Hermite spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline):

> In numerical analysis, a cubic Hermite spline or cubic Hermite
>   interpolator is a spline where each piece is a third-degree polynomial
>   specified in Hermite form: that is, by its values and first derivatives at the
>   end points of the corresponding domain interval.
>
> Cubic Hermite splines
>   are typically used for interpolation of numeric data specified at
>   given argument values x(1), x(2), ..., x(n), to obtain a smooth
>   continuous function. The data should consist of the desired function
>   value and derivative at each x(k). (If only the values are provided,
>   the derivatives must be estimated from them.) The Hermite formula is
>   applied to each interval (x(k), x(k+1)) separately. The resulting
>   spline will be continuous and will have continuous first derivative.
>
> Cubic polynomial splines can be specified in other ways, the Bézier
>   form being the most common. However, these two methods provide the
>   same set of splines, and data can be easily converted between the
>   Bézier and Hermite forms; so the names are often used as if they were
>   synonymous.

Specifying the normals at each point is the same as specifying the tangents (slopes, 1st derivatives), because the latter are perpendicular to the former.

In Matlab, the function for calculating the Piecewise Cubic Hermite Interpolating Polynomial is [`pchip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html). The only problem is that [`pchip` is a bit too clever](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~holzer/cs412/lecture13.pdf):

> The careful reader will notice that pchip takes function values as
>   input, but no derivative values. This is because pchip uses the
>   function values f(x) to estimate the derivative values. [...]  To do a
>   good derivative approximation, the function has to use an
>   approximation using 4 or more points [...] Luckily, using Matlab we
>   can write our own functions to do interpolation using real cubic
>   Hermite splines.

...the author shows how to do this, using the function [`mkpp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mkpp.html).

**2.** If your points are *not* necessarily points of a function, then each interval should be interpolated by a [quadratic Bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve):

[image]

In this example, 3 points are given: the endpoints P(0) and P(2), and P(1), which is the intersection of the tangents at the endpoints. The position of P(1) can be easily calculated from the coordinates of P(0) and P(2), and the normals at these points.

In Matlab, you can use [`spmak`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/spmak.html), see the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10154453/600135) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/constructing-and-working-with-b-form-splines.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function neumann_spline(p, m, q, n)

% example data
p = [0; 1];
q = [2; 5];
m = [0; 1];
n = [1; 1];

if (m(2) ~= 0)
    s1 = atan(-m(1)/m(2));
else
    s1 = pi/2;
end

if (n(2) ~= 0)
    s2 = atan(-n(1)/n(2));
else
    s2 = pi/2;
end

hold on
grid on
axis equal

plot([p(1) p(1)+0.5*m(1)], [p(2) p(2)+0.5*m(2)], 'r', 'Linewidth', 1)
plot([q(1) q(1)+0.5*n(1)], [q(2) q(2)+0.5*n(2)], 'r', 'Linewidth', 1)

sp = csape([p(1) q(1)], [s1 p(2) q(2) s2], [1 1]);
fnplt(sp)

plot(p(1), p(2), 'k.', 'MarkerSize', 16)
plot(q(1), q(2), 'k.', 'MarkerSize', 16)

title('Cubic spline with prescribed normals at the endpoints')

end
```

The result is

[image]